# I want to add a string to an array of strings

Tags: java, arrays, string, data-structures

I have a class and within that class I have a private variable.

```
private String[] stringArray = new String[100]
```

and I have a method in that class like this

```
public void addString (String addedString) {}
```

So I want to add a string into that string Array.
I don't want to use a list, but just add it into a string array with a predetermined number of "empty" elements.

I tried

```
public void addString (String addedString) {
stringArray += addedString;
}
```

But I get an error error: 
incompatible types: String cannot be converted to String[]

Comment: edited "private method" to "private variable"

Answer (score 0):

You can't "add to" an array: it is a fixed-length data structure.

You can create a new array one longer, and set the last element:

```
stringArray = Arrays.copyOf(stringArray, stringArray.length + 1);
stringArray[stringArray.length - 1] = addedString;
```

But honestly, you are better off using a `List` (specifically `ArrayList`) instead, which handles increasing the length of the array for you (and does it more efficiently too, if you are adding lots of elements).

Comment: I'm just using this to understand some concepts so an ArrayList would be better but I want to try to understand how I would do this without an ArrayList. Can I use a for-loop to add the string into the string array instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually add another element to an array, you know, it's an array, it's fixed sized. There already are 100 strings inside it. If you really need to use an array instead of a list, you have to remember the last element with meaningful data in the array and replace the next one:

```
private string[] stringArray = new String[100];
private int meaningful = 0;
public void addString (String addedString) {
    stringArray[meaningful+1] = addedString; // optionally check, whether the array really has enough space like meaningful < 100
    meaningful++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Data {
    private final String[] arr = new String[100];
    private int pos = -1;

    public void add(String str) {
        if(pos < arr.length - 1)
            arr[++pos] = str;
    }

    public String remove() {
        return pos >= 0 ? arr[--pos] : null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void addString (String addedString)
{
    String[] old = stringArray;
    stringArray = new String[old.length + 1];
    for(int i = 0; i < old.length; i++)
        stringArray[i] = old[i];
    stringArray[stringArray.length] = addedString;
}
```

Thats basically the most optimized approach. But you should use ArrayList instead.